# Which formula is this?

Tags: sampling, standard-error

I'm enrolled in a statistics course and missed a few classes so need help in deciphering this formula from a friend's notes. Sorry if this seems a very basic question.

I know the formula is somehow related to Standard Error of the Mean. (SE).

The formula is $\frac{(N-n)}{Nn} s^2$

Comment: It is an unusual formula. Could it perhaps be related to the [finite sample correction factor as applied to the standard error of the mean?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Correction_for_finite_population)

Comment: In this formula I think s is the standard deviation of a sample and N is total population while n is sample size.

Comment: That is likely the case. But no matter which standard formula for $s^2$ one uses, your formula does not quite reproduce the finite sample estimate.  I suspect your professor may be substituting $N$ for the usual $N-1$ in the denominator, but I'm not sure.  Why not ask her/him?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scheaffer et al[1] call
this the "estimated variance of $\bar{y}$", or $\widehat{V}(\bar{y})$

See equation 4.2, p83

(Well, they have $\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)\frac{s^2}{n}$, but it's trivial to show they're the same. They call $\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)$ the $\text{fpc}$, for finite population correction.)

They say that this is an unbiased estimate of $V(\bar{y})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$  (see p81 same reference)

(I was able to locate and view both of those pages in google books, by use of appropriate searches, but what you can see may vary from country to country)
Similar treatment can be found in a number of other books.

[1] Scheaffer, R., William Mendenhall, III, R. Ott, Kenneth Gerow,
*Elementary Survey Sampling*,  7e
Brooks/Cole